# Jest Cannot find module 'setupDevtools' from 'setup.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

New to Jest as my testing suite for a React / Redux application and I am unable to run my `actions` tests due to this error plaguing my application:

> **Test suite failed to run**
>
> *Cannot find module 'setupDevtools' from 'setup.js'*
>
> *at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:191:17)*
>
> *at Object. (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:30:1)*

Removing all content from my test file produces the same error. Here is my Jest config:

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "preset": "jest-react-native",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src/actions/_tests_"
    ]
  }
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "fhirclient": "^0.1.12",
    "full-age-calculator": "0.0.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "verror": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "eslint": "^4.12.1",
    "eslint-config-cerner": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native": "^0.51.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5"
  },
```

I tried a few of the suggestions from [this Github issue page](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3822) which did not resolve my issue.

Comment: I would try more of the suggestions there, and/or post your issue there since it's related and would have more visibility with the people familiar with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started anew today and solved my own problem. As it turns out, Babel has [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) which specifically explains how to setup Jest. In summary, here's what I did:

**Install NPM Modules**

```
npm install --save-dev babel-jest
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env
```

or with one command:

```
npm install i -d babel-jest babel-preset-env
```

**Create .babelrc Config File**

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

**Modify package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is some [further reading](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) on why the `env preset` configuration is needed. Happy coding!